# how to fit 3 gridview in a div horizontally with scroll in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

i have three gridview i want them to fit in 1 div with scroll so when i scroll all three will move. This is what ive done..

```
<div class="headerleft" style=" width:1299px; height:440px;  border:1px solid gray; overflow: auto; ">
             <div id="Div2"  style="margin:50px; width:3300px;">

                      <asp:GridView ID="goutlet" emptydatatext="No data available." runat="server"  
                              Width="1000px" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="gridview">
                      </asp:GridView>


        <asp:GridView ID="gtracking" runat="server"  emptydatatext="No data available." 
                AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"  HorizontalAlign=NotSet
                Width="1000px" ShowFooter="True"  OnRowDataBound="gtracking_RowDataBound"
                           onselectedindexchanged="gtracking_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                           CssClass="gridview" 
                >
        </asp:GridView>
                 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  HorizontalAlign="Right" >
                 </asp:GridView>
      </div>

                     </div>
```

Comment: please rewrite your question

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code with sample data and it worked correctly. You can create three equal divs inside one div, each with a GridView.

```
    <div style="width:2100px;">

         <div style="width:700px; float:left; height:200px;">

                   <asp:GridView ID="goutlet" emptydatatext="No data available." runat="server"  
                          ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gridview">
                  </asp:GridView>
          </div>

          <div style="width:700px; float:left; height:200px;">

                  <asp:GridView ID="gtracking" runat="server"  emptydatatext="No data available." 
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        ShowFooter="True"  OnRowDataBound="gtracking_RowDataBound"
                       onselectedindexchanged="gtracking_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="gridview" >
          </div>

          <div style="width:700px; float:left; height:200px;">

                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                  </asp:GridView>
          </div>

  </div>
```